# Selenium 4 Relative Locator - How to locate the First Name input box using Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium4, relative-locators

I am unable to enter the text in the input box which is to the right of the label "FirstName" using selenium 4 toRightOf.

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/register&language=en-gb");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
WebElement fName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='First Name']"));
System.out.println(fName.isDisplayed());
driver.findElement(RelativeLocator.with(By.tagName("input")).toRightOf(fName)).sendKeys("Testuser1");
```

Comment: You should label your question clearly with `Java`. I wrote a solution for you in Python, before noticing this is, in fact, Java.

Answer (score 1):

### [Relative Locators](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/#relative-locators)

Relative Locators (previously called as Friendly Locators) was introduced in [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4). These locators are helpful when it is a bit difficult to construct a locator for the desired element, but easy to describe spatially the desired element where the element is in relation to an element that does have an easily constructed [locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver).

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) uses the JavaScript function [**getBoundingClientRect()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to determine the size and position of elements on the page, and can use this information to locate neighboring elements. [Relative locator methods](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-4-relative-locators) can take as the argument for the point of origin, either a previously located element reference, or another locator.

---

### Solution

To send a character sequence to the **First Name** `<input>` you can use the following solution:

```
driver.get("https://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/register&language=en-gb");
WebElement labelFirstName =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(., 'First Name')]")); By
firstName = RelativeLocator.with(By.tagName("input")).near(labelFirstName);
driver.findElement(firstName).sendKeys("Bimlesh");
```

Optimizing the code:

```
driver.get("https://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/register&language=en-gb");
driver.findElement(RelativeLocator.with(By.tagName("input")).near(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(., 'First Name')]")))).sendKeys("Bimlesh");
```

Inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447):

```
driver.get("https://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/register&language=en-gb");
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(RelativeLocator.with(By.tagName("input")).near(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(., 'First Name')]"))))).sendKeys("Bimlesh");
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: RelativeLocator_Java]

---

### This usecase

Having said that, it's appears sending a text to the **First Name** `<input>` box would be easier using either of the regular [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over) as follows:

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/register&language=en-gb");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#input-firstname"))).sendKeys("Bimlesh");
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/register&language=en-gb");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='input-firstname']"))).sendKeys("Bimlesh");
  ```