# The method above(WebElement) in the type relativelocator.relativeby is not applicable for the argument (string)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
driver.get("https://urlk/my-account/");
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
driver.findElement(RelativeLocator.with(By.tagName("input")).above("password")).sendKeys("hi");
```

.above in the code is highlighted in red and shows the following when I hover: the method above(WebElement) in the type relativelocator.relativeby is not applicable for the argument (string)

I am working on selenium locator tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. [`above`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/#above) expects a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805139/7429447) but not the string *`"password"`*.

---

### Solution

So effectively your line of code will be:

```
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
driver.findElement(RelativeLocator.with(By.tagName("input")).above(password)).sendKeys("hi");
```

In a single line:

```
driver.findElement(RelativeLocator.with(By.tagName("input")).near(driver.findElement(By.id("password")))).sendKeys("hi");
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium 4 Relative Locator - How to locate the First Name input box using Selenium with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73052590/7429447)

Comment: Why was the quotation mark "" missing in .above(password)) , also I noticed that while the URL actually opened, the sendkeys value "hi" is not passed in the form. I have also test with URL: Facebook.com

Comment: @taerese _Why was the quotation mark "" missing in .above(password))_: See at the beinging of the answer _`above` expects a WebElement but not any string_